# HowTo access the text within <div> tag

Tags: css

I have the following

```
<div id='staff' >Staff</div>
```

I would like to place an asterisk after the 'Staff' text to indicate that the associated component is REQUIRED.

How can I access the 'Staff' text using CSS3 and polymer-dart so I can insert the asterisk immediately after 'Staff'?

Comment: :D What kind of access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is for dart-polymer

```
* /deep/ #staff::after {
  content: " *";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150%;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)? If so add the following to your style sheet:

```
#staff {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}
```